# How to select text area in Selenium which has a HTML code as follows

Tags: java, selenium, textarea

```
<textarea rows="7" cols="125" name="nomText1Line1" required="required"></textarea>
```

I tried using `driver.findElement(By.name("nomText1Line1"));` didn't work

Comment: you are correct here `driver.findElement(By.name("nomText1Line1"));`  It should work..

Comment: Can you post your URL?

Comment: ya it is working, it was not getting highlighted so i tried sendKeys() it worked fine .... thank you

Answer (score 0):

The way you mentioned is the easiest way to select your element. Are you sure there are no syntactical mistakes? This should work:

```
WebElement textArea = driver.findElement(By.name("nomText1Line1"));
```

If you are trying to get the contents of the text area then something like this:

```
String textArea = driver.findElement(By.name("nomText1Line1")).getText();
```

Comment: ya it is working, it was not getting highlighted, so i tried sendKeys() it worked fine .... thank you